# From first-order logic to natural language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have this statement in FOL:
$$∀x. (\mathrm{smart}(x) \lor ¬\mathrm{student}(x))$$
The natural language translation is$$
\text{All students are smart.}
$$
I am not sure how this is concluded from FOL because it just says $x$ is either smart or not a student.

Can I convert the FOL as follows in order to conclude this statement?
$$∀x. (\mathrm{smart}(x) \lor ¬\mathrm{student}(x))\\
∀x. (¬\mathrm{student}(x) \lor \mathrm{smart}(x))\\
∀x. (\mathrm{student}(x) → \mathrm{smart}(x))
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how this is concluded from FOL because it just says x is either smart or not a student.

Correction, it says: *everything* is smart or not a student.

So clearly: if any thing is a student, then it must be smart.

> Can I convert the FOL as follows in order to conclude this statement:

Yes.  $\forall x~(\def\smart{\operatorname{smart}}\smart(x)\vee\neg\def\student{\operatorname{student}}\student(x))~\equiv~\forall x~(\student(x)\to\smart(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use the equivalence between :

> $\lnot p \lor q$

and :

> $p \to q$.

See : [Material implication (rule of inference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$\text{student(x)='x' is student}$

$\text{smart(x)='x' is smart}$

All student are smart can be written as-:

> $\forall x (\text{student(x)} \rightarrow \text{smart(x)})$

on expanding it further,

> $\forall x (\text{student(x)}^{'} +\text{smart(x)})$

as $p \rightarrow q =p^{'} +q$